# How to retrieve dataset names from python statsmodels?

Tags: python, statsmodels

The Python statsmodels library grants access to many R-datasets which can be downloaded e.g. with:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset(dataname='iris', package='datasets').data
```

But for this you have to know the id or the name of the dataset.

```
sm.datasets.get_rdataset??
Signature: sm.datasets.get_rdataset(dataname, package='datasets', cache=False)
Source:   
def get_rdataset(dataname, package="datasets", cache=False):
    """download and return R dataset

    Parameters
    ----------
    dataname : str
        The name of the dataset you want to download
```

There is a list of available datasets [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/datasets/index.html), but this list does not contain the identifiers. Also not the [detailed view](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/datasets/generated/co2.html).

Is there an overview of all the available datasets that contains the ids e.g. "iris"?

There is an [index](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html) that is supposed to list all the datasets, but e.g. 'rice' as a name does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the website of the creator of rdatasets I guess with the info you are looking for:

http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html

Here is a short look at it:

```
Package     Item    Title   Rows    Cols    n_binary    n_character     n_factor    n_logical   n_numeric   CSV     Doc
boot    acme    Monthly Excess Returns  60  3   0   1   0   0   2   CSV     DOC
boot    aids    Delay in AIDS Reporting in England and Wales    570     6   1   0   0   0   6   CSV     DOC
boot    aircondit   Failures of Air-conditioning Equipment  12  1   0   0   0   0   1   CSV     DOC
boot    aircondit7  Failures of Air-conditioning Equipment  24  1   0   0   0   0   1   CSV     DOC
boot    amis    Car Speeding and Warning Signs  8437    4   1   0   0   0   4   CSV     DOC
boot    aml     Remission Times for Acute Myelogenous Leukaemia     23  3   2   0   0   0   3   CSV     DOC 
...
```

I assume the Item column are the identifiers.

Comment: As stated above, that does not seem to work. Try for example 'rice'.

Comment: Did you change the package parameter to DAAG for the dataset rice? Since it’s not in the package datasets according to the index site.

Answer (score 1):

You can view all the available datasets at this URL https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/blob/master/datasets.csv

The available ones in statsmodels are those with the tag `datasets` which looks like line 372 - 455.

I didn't test them all, but everyone I tried from a small random sample seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this code to get all modules in datasets:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import inspect

def get_list_of_modules_in_datasets():
  # get list of strings for the objects in datasets
  list_str_in_datasets = sm.datasets.__all__
  print(list_str_in_datasets)
  # get list of objects in datasets
  list_objs_in_datasets = [eval('sm.datasets.' + dsstr) for dsstr in list_str_in_datasets]
  print(list_objs_in_datasets)
  # get list of modules in datasets
  list_modules_in_datasets = []
  for dso in list_objs_in_datasets:
    if (inspect.ismodule(dso)):
      list_modules_in_datasets.append(dso)
  print(list_modules_in_datasets)
  print("Number of Modules in datasets = %d" %(len(list_modules_in_datasets)))
  return (list_modules_in_datasets)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  list_modules_in_datasets = get_list_of_modules_in_datasets()

  # print data for all dataframes from the datasets
  for ds in list_modules_in_datasets:
    df = ds.load_pandas().data
    print(list(df.columns))
    print(df.shape)
    print(df)
```